# git/ssh - Having trouble with ssh authentication with multiple users

Tags: git, ssh, config, git-config

I am having trouble getting git ssh authentication to work with multiple users.
Initially, it would always try to authenticate with my home-key

`~/.ssh/home-key`,

untill I found this answer

https://gist.github.com/Jonalogy/54091c98946cfe4f8cdab2bea79430f9?permalink_comment_id=3700405#gistcomment-3700405

I ran that command and success. It worked, however now I have the opposite issue, and it always tries to autenticate with
`~/.ssh/work-01`
Despite having that and
`~/.ssh/home-01`

I know the git config file is correct because in my work repo, when I run

`gitconfig user.email`

I get

```
rob@Robs-MBP test % git config user.email
work@mywork.co.uk
```

and likewise when in my home-repo

I get

```
rob@Robs-MacBook-Pro ~ % git config user.email
home@googlemail.com
```

As far as I am aware, my ~/.ssh/config file is correct

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com-home
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/rob/.ssh/home-01
  IdentitiesOnly yes

#wearenv-git
Host github.com-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/rob/.ssh/work-01
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and my global git config file is this

```
[user]
    name = home-username 
    email = home@googlemail.com 
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work-repos"]
    path = /work-repos/.gitconfig
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
[color]
    ui = auto
[core]
    editor = code --wait
```

the `includeIf` points to this

```
[user]
    name = work-username
    email = work@work.co.uk
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
[color]
    ui = auto
[core]
    editor = code --wait
```

and even setting a local config file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:wearenv-digital/test.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main 
[user]
    name = work-username
    email = work@work.co.uk
```

I have checked, double checked and triple checked I have the correct key files uploaded to git.

Git can authenticate using work.key, as shown in this:

```
rob@Robs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ssh -i~/.ssh/work-01  git@github.com 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi work-username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
rob@Robs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

It seems that when I only have `work01` in `ssh-agent`, it always tries to authenticate with work@work.co.uk

Vice versa with `home-01`

Then when both keys are in the `ssh-agent`, it always tries to use the first one added.

EDIT
I can provide the verbose output of

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/work-01 git@github.com
```

eg

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/work-01 -v git@github.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

> ```
> #Default GitHub
> Host github.com-home
>   HostName github.com
>   User git
>   IdentityFile /Users/rob/.ssh/home-01
>   IdentitiesOnly yes
>
> #wearenv-git
> Host github.com-work
>   HostName github.com
>   User git
>   IdentityFile /Users/rob/.ssh/work-01
>   IdentitiesOnly yes
> ```

is correct, assuming the identities are in the named files, i.e., `.ssh/home-01` and `.ssh/work-01` in your home directory which is `/Users/rob`.  You can make this simpler by writing:

```
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/home-01
```

for instance as `~` means "my home directory" and hence this is automatically the right `~/.ssh/` directory and all you have to get right is the file name.

But this part is wrong:

```
ssh -i~/.ssh/work-01 git@github.com
```

Well, *wrong* is too strong: it works fine, it's just overkill.  What you want is much simpler:

```
ssh github.com-home
```

to "log in" to `git@github.com` using your home identity, and

```
ssh github.com-work
```

to "log in" to `git@github.com` using your work identity.  That is, *instead of* `github.com` we use the faked up "host name".  I would spell this `gh-work` and `gh-home` for short myself:

```
Host gh-work
    User git
```

[etc] so that the "host name" is the unqualified string `gh-work` or `gh-home`, which is shorter and easier to type.

On your Mac, you may first need to run:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/work-01
```

and:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/home-01
```

(though just once after you've rebooted).<sup>1</sup>  Use `ssh-add -l` to list the IDs that your agent knows about.

---

<sup>1</sup>This makes use of the fact that macOS starts the ssh agent *for you* when you log in, providing the right environment variables to each shell opened in each terminal window.  This way every terminal window opened from the time you log in *shares* a *single agent process*.  There's no need to start one.  Linux systems typically require you to start one as you log in, which in turn requires some fancy footwork in a `.bashrc` or `.profile` or other startup file.  The macOS environment makes this much easier.

---

#### Making Git uses the right URL

Once the above works—you can easily test it with `ssh -Tv github.com-home` and so on, as you've written things—you simply need to convince *Git* to clone from, and push to, repositories stored on `ssh://github.com-home/personal/repo` and `ssh://github.com-work/work/repo` for instance.

This is where this kind of trick comes in:

> ```
> [includeIf "gitdir:~/work-repos"]
>     path = ~/work-repos/.gitconfig
> ```

(Note that I have added a `~` character that I think you dropped).

What we can do with `includeIf` is:

- set `user.name` and `user.email` for work vs personal repos
- make Git use an `insteadOf` rule for `ssh://github.com/` URLs

**and** (this is the reason for the `includeIf` part) make the *actual substitution* conditional on whether this is a "work" or "home" repository based on where it lives in our home directories.

If you put your work repositories in `~/work-repos/*` (as indicated here) and your personal ones elsewhere (perhaps ~/home-repos/*`? use whatever you like; as you've set this up only the` ~/work-repos/*`ones get the work treatment), *and* add these lines to`~/work-repos/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "ssh://github.com-work/"]
    insteadOf = ssh://github.com/
```

Now if you run:

```
git clone ssh://github.com/company/repo.git
```

Git will take that and *change it* to read:

```
git clone ssh://github.com-work/company/repo.git
```

This in turn will cause Git to run:

```
ssh github.com-work git-upload-...
```

That is, Git will ask ssh to connect to a host named `github.com-work` and run the smart protocol to access the company repository in `company/repo.git`.

We already know (and have tested) that `ssh github.com-work` actually connects *to* `github.com`, not `github.com-work`, and logs in as the work user using the work-user public-key so that your ssh command is correctly identified as "you-at-$company".  This user therefore *has access to* the company repo and can clone it.

If you don't mind typing in the "wrong" URL (including the home/work distinction) in the first place, you don't need the `insteadOf` trick.  The fact that you're using a fake host name will trigger ssh into using the desired *identity* on the *real* (`github.com`) host.  But adding the `insteadOf` trick makes this even more convenient.

Since many people may use `git@github.com:user/repo.git` instead of `ssh://github.com/user/repo.git`, or add `git@` in front of `github.com` to get `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git`, you may want multiple `insteadOf` rules here, e.g.:

```
[url "ssh://github.com-work/"]
    insteadOf = ssh://github.com/
    insteadOf = ssh://git@github.com/
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

There are many ways to work this, of course.  Pick one that suits you best.  *Start* by getting `ssh` to work the way you want, without adding Git into the mix at all.  Then add Git, knowing that ssh is working the way you want.

Comment: Hi! Thankyou so much for responding so promptly!
Rebooting (once I readded the identites into ssh-add) worked! btw I only used the longer `ssh-add -i ~/.ssh/home-01 -v git@github.com-home` to try and trace the issue once i realised that the connection was attempting to authenticate with the wrong ssh-key! I cant believe it was something as simple as rebooting.. **Have you tried turning it off and on again?**